# slide out animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a link, when the user clicks on a link, I want jquery to animate a box that slides out from the link.

I got it to do that using the code below:

```
box.animate({width: 500px, height:500px}, "fast");
```

but this slides out to the bottom. However I make it slide out towards the top? Also, how can I "reverse" the side (currently, it slides to the right. How can I make it slide left)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change its position as well,

```
$('#box').animate({width: '500px', 
                   height:'500px', 
                   'left': '-=500px', 
                   'top':'-=500px'}, "fast");
```

Comment: @user666423 If it is positioned absolutely then yes. Updated for that

Answer (score 1):

Position the item as if it were visible on the screen, whether it be towards the top or left. For convenience you could use JQuery UI position to place the element. 
Then hide the element JQuery.hide() and use JQuery.show() setting the effect parameter to side.

Comment: well, the thing is I don't want it to just slide out...instead "expand out". JQuery doesn't seem to have an built in animation for that.